# Detect if a jsonb attribute is array or object

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb

Many jsonb/json functions expect all values of the column either to be of type json array ( like `jsonb_array_length` ) or only an json object (like `jsonb_build_oject`) .

There are some jsonb columns in the database which contain a mix of both arrays and object roots, is there any easy way to filter out arrays and objects so that queries like

```
SELECT DISTINCT jsonb_object_keys(my_column) FROM my_table;
 cannot call jsonb_object_keys on an array
```

or

```
SELECT my_column FROM my_table WHERE jsonb_array_length(column) > 0;
cannot get array length of a non-array
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

As described in [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html) the functions `jsonb_typeof` or `json_typeof` can be used to apply this kind of filtering

like

```
SELECT DISTINCT jsonb_object_keys(my_column) 
FROM my_table WHERE jsonb_typeof(column) ='object' ;
```

or

```
SELECT my_column FROM my_table 
WHERE jsonb_array_length(column) > 0 
AND jsonb_typeof(column) ='array' ;
```